# Using the theme options to change background

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, theme-options

how do I add some options to a theme? 
I would like to add support, in my thmes, for dinamically changing the page background.
I don't even know how to start.

I think I can break down this issue in two questions:

1. how do I add a "theme options page"
2. how do I create a function that prints the link to an uploaded
   image, so I can hardcode the css in my header.php

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For theme Settings see Chip Bennett's [tutorial](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/), also WordPress supports custom background, you can add support to your theme with `add_custom_background`, see [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_background) for more information.

Comment: For the purposes of the question as stated, the OP should definitely be using `add_custom_background()` to implement custom backgrounds.